# Ember.js FindRecord Invalid Id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I'm trying to see if a entry exists on an API call that returns `{data:null}` if the entry does not exist. When the call resolves I get the following error:

`Cannot read property 'constructor' of null`

What I want to do is if the entry doesn't exist I want to create it. If it does exist I want to update the model. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Also I created the API to fit JSON API standards so I can change the response of the server as well.

Comment: Maybe api should return 404 if entity is not there (and no payload), that may help. If you want just `ping` api you can use [ajax addon](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax). But that may be little overkill. And last option that comes to mind is that this error is probably from serializer. So overriding that to handle this case should be also viable option.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Keo that it may be easier to customize the response code from the API, but if you don't have access to the API code, you can intercept the payload in the `normalizeResponse` in the serializer to do the check there.

```js
import JSONAPISerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/json-api';

export default JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  /**
   * normalize the response from the server to a format
   * that ember data will work well with
   */
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    if (!payload || !payload.data) {
      // react to empty payload here
    } else {
      // pass through the payload with data to the store 
      return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);      
    }
  }
});
```